# What happens if we don't use DTOs in our API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

For Example: "Student" is Domain Model and i am using the "student" object directly in my API Action method.

```
        // Domain Model.
        pubic class Student
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string FirstName{ get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Gender{ get; set; }
            public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        }

       //Simple API method that Add new student details to the database.
       [HttpPost]
       public IHttpActionResult GetStudents(Student student)
       {
           if (!ModelState.IsValid)
               return BadRequest();

              _context_.student.Add(student);
              _context_.SaveChanges();
              return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/"), student.Id);
       }
```

Comment: 1. You're exposing your internal domain 2. What if `Student` has fields which you don't want to send to the client? let's say password hash

Comment: What else do you want to use? I don´t get your question.

Comment: HimBromBeere ! ... i am asking that ! in the above example the student is a domain model and i am using student object in my api action  method... for example if i create a dto and instead of using  student object i am studentDTO !!!!  so what will be the exact difference  between these two approches. ? (i an new to asp.web api.. {and i am confused so much}).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have a chance to expose your domain model to untrusted clients.
2. Most of the times DTO's are lighter which result in less data transferred.
3. Sometimes domain model have complex types included.

   ```
   public class Student
   {
       //...
       public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
   }
   public class Course
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       //...
   }
   ```

This might not satisfy the client. You have to either serialize domain object or use DTO to flatten the object.

4. Your API will evolve with your domain model if you don't use DTO's. This might break your external consumers apps when your API is public.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine, for DTO is what it means, Data Transfer Object. Unless your views have a different need, then using a model based on a DTO is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It really will save you time in future. I mean if you are developing really long term solution you must use `DTO` and make you code more structured. You must have different layers. Like data layer, presentation layer, business layer etc. And all this layers are supposed to be independent. If you use `DTO` you are able to create more specific entities. Without mixing up your business logic.

And I've also seen this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1050468/Data-Transfer-Object-Design-Pattern-in-Csharp). Probably it gets you some examples where `DTO` can help you.

> DTO (Data Transfer objects) is a data container for moving data
>   between layers. They are also termed as transfer objects. DTO is only
>   used to pass data and does not contain any business logic. They only
>   have simple setters and getters.

Comment: I don't think that MUST is a good word for this. Nothing is a must in programming. DTO's are not must for sure. By this I don't mean to use domain object insted of DTO's ofcourse. Also layered architecture is not recipe for success in all cases.

Comment: @MichałK.Yea, good point. But using layered architecture is one of criteria of success for long term project. And using DTO is one of examples using of layered architecture.

Comment: I can't agree. Not all long running projects must have layered architecture. You should watch Jimmy Bogard talk about vertical slice architecture. It's absolutely beautiful and simple. And this is a best part - He have Github with complete solution how to. So it's not only theoretical.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUiWfhAhgQw&index=12&list=PL03Lrmd9CiGcqxJg1msfNXQ8tHLhXs4O7

Comment: @MichałK it's up to you of course. what ever you want. if you not agree with word must i can change it )

Comment: Hell no! You don't have to change your opinion, heck you even don't have to watch the talk. I just gave you example of not so layered architecture which amazes me. Nothing more nothing less. :)